# Show that $\sqrt{-n}$ and $\sqrt{-n} +1$ are not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n} ]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

What I have done is that tried writing $\sqrt{-n} =(a+b\sqrt{-n}  )(c+d\sqrt{-n} ) $ .

And also $-n =(a^2+b^2(-n)) (c^2+d^2(-n)) $. (Using the definition of norms.) 
This however didn't yield me something useful. And also how do you attempt such problems in general?

Comment: Do you know what a prime element is?

Comment: Yes if $p|ab $ then $p|a $ or $p|b$

Comment: So $\sqrt{-n}|(a+b\sqrt{-n})$ hence $n|a$ .So suppose $a =n$ and $(n+b\sqrt{-n})(c+d\sqrt{-n})$.

Comment: So if I calculate I am getting $b=c/(c^2+d^2n)$ how do I proceed after this @user26857

Comment: There is another characterization which is more useful here: p is prime iff the factor ring R/(p) is an integral domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]\simeq\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+n)$ and show:

1. $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]/(\sqrt{-n})\simeq \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$
2. $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]/(\sqrt{-n}+1)\simeq \mathbb Z/(n+1)\mathbb Z$

Comment: I suppose that $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: None of your claims is actually true, in general.

Comment: One more doubt I have. How would the ideal generated by (2,$\sqrt{-n}$)look like? Will it be a principal ideal?@user26857

Comment: Again too general question. If $n=1,2$ the ring is a principal ideal domain, so every ideal is principal. See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711611