# Elementary proof that If $n+1$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $1+\sqrt{-n}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $n+1$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $1+\sqrt{-n}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$.

I believe this statement is true based on the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3610560/

However, I'd like an elementary proof that doesn't involve ring quotients.

By adapting the proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3566198 ,
I have an elementary proof of the following similar statement: If $n$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, then $\sqrt{-n}$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$.
But I can't see how to further adapt it.

Comment: By "extensions" do you mean "quotients"?

Comment: How can you have a proof of a statement with $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ in it "that doesn't involve ring extensions"? As soon as you mention $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ you're involving ring extensions, because $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ _is_ a ring extension.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin fixed

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an elementary argument that, assuming $n+1$ is prime, if $1 + \sqrt{-n}$ divides $(a + b\sqrt{-n})(c + d\sqrt{-n})$, then $1 + \sqrt{-n}$ divides $a + b\sqrt{-n}$ or it divides $c + d\sqrt{-n}$.

Writing $(a + b\sqrt{-n})(c + d\sqrt{-n}) = (1 + \sqrt{-n})(u + v\sqrt{-n})$ and expanding, we have two equations

$$ac - bdn = u - nv, \qquad bc + ad = u + v.$$
Subtracting these equations and rearranging, we may derive

$$(a - b)(c - d) = (n+1)(bd - v)$$
and since $n+1$ is prime, it must divide either $a - b$ or $c - d$, say the former without loss of generality. Write $a - b = k(n+1)$, so that $a = b + k(n+1)$ and therefore

$$a + b\sqrt{-n} = k(n+1) + b + b\sqrt{-n} = k(n+1) + b(1 + \sqrt{-n})$$

or in other words

$$a + b\sqrt{-n} = (1 + \sqrt{-n})(k(1 - \sqrt{-n}) + b)$$
which was to be shown.

Comment: It's elementary, i.e., doesn't require concepts from abstract algebra, but it *is* arguably the sort of grungy proof that abstract algebra succeeds so well in cleaning up and clearing up, so that people don't get lost in the forest.